# How to fix new build warnings after upgrading to Clang 14 / C++2b?

Tags: c++, enums, warnings

wish you all a great day.
I upgraded my source code to Clang 14 / C++2b.With the new Clang / c++ version, a lot of warnings have emerged while building the game.

These are the new warnings that came with the new Clang / c++ while building game:

> -Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion
> -Winvalid-source-encoding
> -Wunused-private-field
> -Wambiguous-reversed-operator
> -Wmisleading-indentation
> -Wunused-const-variable
> -W#pragma-messages
> -Wdeprecated
> -Wdeprecated-anon-enum-enum-conversion

I had to suppress -Winvalid-source-encoding warnings since they were literally spamming on the console. Every single file with Korean characters (EUC-KR encoding) throw this error now.

Another almost spamming warning is the -Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion one. For example it throws this warning

```
./../../common/item_length.h:154:46: warning: arithmetic between different enumeration types ('EDragonSoulSubType' and 'EDragonSoulGradeTypes') is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-enum-enum-conversion]
    DRAGON_SOUL_INVENTORY_MAX_NUM = DS_SLOT_MAX * DRAGON_SOUL_GRADE_MAX * DRAGON_SOUL_BOX_SIZE,
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

for this code

```
enum EDSInventoryMaxNum{
DRAGON_SOUL_INVENTORY_MAX_NUM = DS_SLOT_MAX * DRAGON_SOUL_GRADE_MAX * DRAGON_SOUL_BOX_SIZE,};
```

How may I change this code to make it fit in the new c++2b standard?

Here is the full log while building my game
https://pastebin.com/hpd3pwk2

OS: FreeBSD 13.0
Build system: Gmake

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Wrap each value in `std::to_underlying(...)`? Or `int(...)` if you don't feel fancy.

Comment: thank you for your answer! @HolyBlackCat however, I get the error that "namespace std has no member to_underlying" I have tried to include <type_traits> and <utility> but no luck.

./../../common/length.h:693:31: error: no matching function for call to 'to_underlying'
        DRAGON_SOUL_EQUIP_SLOT_END = std::to_underlying(DRAGON_SOUL_EQUIP_SLOT_START) + std::to_underlying((DS_SLOT_MAX * DRAGON_SOUL_DECK_MAX_NUM)),

Comment: It's a C++23 function, might not be implemented yet in your standard library. Read how it works on cppreference.